# Dynamic Data Masking : why the value =0 but should be >0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-data-masking

I am testing Dynamic Data Masking using the article

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7887/dynamic-data-masking-in-sql-server-for-sensitive-data-protection/

The question is:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestManager2'
SELECT * FROM Employee
update Employee set ServicePeriodInYears = ServicePeriodInYears+1 where FirstName='Aram'
-- 0 but ServicePeriodInYears >0
update Employee set ServicePeriodInYears = 11 where FirstName='Sos'
-- 11
REVERT
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

The 1st update set the value always to 0 and did not change. But the 2nd works correctly = 11.
Can anybody explain me why it is?

Comment: sorry but i cannot recreate the issue you're having. see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/2-bewk90 it doesn't work in the fiddle, but if you run this script, both rows gets updated just fine

Comment: Add this and try how the user update   CREATE USER TestManager3 WITHOUT LOGIN
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE ON Employee TO TestManager3
GRANT UNMASK ON Employee(WorkPhoneNumber) TO TestManager3

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestManager3'
update Employee set ServicePeriodInYears = ServicePeriodInYears+1 where FirstName='Aram'
REVERT
SELECT * FROM Employee
GO

Comment: Hmm, no, that doesn't work. The question is, if it's by design or a bug :)

Comment: Yes, it was a reason why I have asked. May be it is by design but I did not find in the MS doc not about it. As for me: it is dangerous because update works OK but data updated incorrectly.

Comment: Adding the DDL to your question would help us help you. From [Limitations and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations-and-restrictions): "Whenever you project an expression referencing a column for which a data masking function is defined, the expression is also masked. Regardless of the function (default, email, random, custom string) used to mask the referenced column, the resulting expression will always be masked with the default function."

Comment: Ok, but finally: user1 selects masked field2, then user1 does update set field2=... then the field2 will contain incorrect data in the db for any users  because physical value is destorted?

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch - did you grant unmask for those table columns to TestManager2?
If not, despite the value being > 0, you may well fail to see it when queried. Your update is effectively trying to retrieve the current value before incrementing.

Comment: The matter is: I am trying to understand how user can update fields records but he selects masked data in these fields.